# Setup and deployment in .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, setup-deployment

How do I make the setup and deployment project to include my resources in the installed [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project?

My resources are in the default resources folder and its information is in the `properties.resources.resx` file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .resx from the WindowsUI layer folder file in your project